# bad assets Heroku links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with Heroku and when i try to deploy my app it doesn't run the `run assets:precompile` and I haven't precompiled my assets locally, I do not have de manifest file in Git.

My app is using cedar, I run 
    `heroku stack`

The result is
    `bamboo-mri-1.9.2

    bamboo-ree-1.8.7

    * cedar`

In my deployed application i get `<link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` insted of `<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in Heroku. Locally, when I run `rails s` on the command prompt the assets are fine.

My application is made in Ruby on Rails. My config/application.rb

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
#require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Mongoapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
     config.time_zone = 'Bogota'


    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    # config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true


    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

My application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= display_meta_tags%>
  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- fav and touch icons -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">  
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head>
<%=render "layouts/header"%>
<body>
<% flash.each do |key,value|%>
    <%if key==:notice%>
      <%key=:info%>
    <%end%>
  <%if key==:alert%>
      <%key=:error%>
    <%end%>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>" id="flash_<%=key%>">
      <div class="container"><%= value %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="document.getElementById('flash_<%=key%>').style.display='none';">×</button>
    </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
</body>
<%=render "layouts/footer"%>
</html>
```

My environments/production.rb

```
Mongoapp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'inkognitmongo.herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.sendgrid.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "inkognitmongo.herokuapp.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
}

  config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css bootstrap.js jquery.js jquery.easing.1.3.js raphael-min.js google-code-prettify/prettify.js prettify.js jquery.elastislide.js jquery.tweet.js jquery.prettyPhoto.js jquery.flexslider.js iview.js jquery-hover-effect.js animate.js custom.js .svg .eot .woff .ttf)
end
```

Comment: "Bad Assets" would be a great name for a band.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, add the following to your `application.rb` to enable precompilation of your pipeline on Heroku:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Then, in your Heroku console (accessible via the Heroku Toolbelt by typing `heroku run console` from command line), manually precompile using the following command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Finally, restart your app by typing `heroku restart` – your asset pipeline should be correctly precompiled.

**UPDATE**:

If the above solution is still not setting the correct path, you have a manifest file that's causing the default asset path to be overridden by your tag helpers. You can resolve this by deleting the `manifest.yml` file from the `public/assets/` directory, committing your changes, then redeploying to Heroku.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added the line to the application.rb and I tried to precompile my assets locally and upload them to Heroku, then I pushed the app and now my images appear in the website. But the link is still `<link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` insted of `<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`. When I put in the browser ´http://myapp.herokuapp.com/assets/application.css` is there. What is the problem?

Comment: How are you loading these tags in `application.html.erb`? Can you post the source code? Also, do you have any files inside your `public/assets/` directory, and if so, which ones?

Comment: I posted my application.html.erb. In my plublic/assets/ directory I have jquery, some fonts, application.css, some *.js. Finally I have some directories ico, img and a manifest.yml file... I also posted the envirnoments/production.rb